# Run requestAnimationFrame in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, video-streaming, tokbox

I am using requestAnimationFrame to animate video streams and I know that request animation does not work in backgrounds so is there any way to make it run on background.

I know that we can animate using setInterval or setTimeout too but when I use these, animations were not work properly and images on video stream were blinking.

Here is my code:

```
const drawFrame = function drawFrame() {
            if (!ctx) {
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            }
            if (!tmpCanvas) {
              tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
              tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
              tmpCanvas.width = canvas.width;
              tmpCanvas.height = canvas.height;
            }
            tmpCtx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height);
            const imgData = tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height);
            const data = selectedFilter(imgData);
            ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
            if (!stopped) {
              requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
            } else {
              tmpCanvas = null;
              tmpCtx = null;
              ctx = null;
            }
        };
        requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The library we are using, uses requestAnimationFrame() and it is too late to change at this point in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are out of luck. requestAnimationFrame intentionally pauses in the background because animations have no reason to be running in the background, and as you mention setInterval and setTimeout are not designed for animation and should not be used as such.

You mention that you need to animate a video stream. Do you mean that you are applying an animation on top of a video tag, or changing the appearance of the video element via a canvas element? In both cases, you shouldn't continue to do so in the background anyway, but you may give [computeFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas) (Firefox only) a go, which will fire once every frame of the video. Or is it that you are actually faking a video stream by animating a set of static images in succession? In that case, why are you not using the video element?

Comment: Actually, I am using Tokbox js API which not support change stream in run time and we have a need to add effects (static image) on video and for this we are using camera-filter API which uses requestAnimationFrame but as I mention it will not run in background so is there any way to overcome from this?

Comment: requestAnimationFrame was specifically designed to run once per animation with a RTS priority on foreground tabs, but not background tabs. Doing so in the background would cause performance issues. Not everything in a browser can be prioritized. I know of no other cross-browser way you can simulate a requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: And setTimeout/setInterval is not intended for this. If you set a timeout for 30 ms, the only guarantee you get is that it will not fire until _at least_ 30 ms has passed. When 30 ms has passed, it will start to wait for the currently running context to finish running (as Javascript is a [mostly] single-threaded language). On top of this, a browser may very well try to throttle this further to save system resources. Or, if a lot of javascript is running in multiple tabs, the operating system can throttle the browser itself, only giving it access to a certain number of cores.